# how can i get the while loop to terminate when all matrix values are <0 and create a vector based on each iteration? in python 3

Tags: python, matrix, while-loop, simulation, montecarlo

***I have edited the infect function and included a vaccinate function which both run and produce new matrices. However, for i==n and j==m, the infect function says that it is improperly indexed and it wont write to the right and bottom boundary of the function

```
import random
from copy import copy
import numpy as np


def infect(Pop,i,j,n,m, tau):
    B = copy(Pop)
    if (i==n):        #this is how I have tried to get around this matrix boundary issue
        if (j==0):    #but when I run it, the code behaves exactly as it did when this wasnt here
            is_infected = False
            for neighbor in [Pop[i-1,j],Pop[i,j+1]]:
                if neighbor:
                    B[i,j] = int(Pop[i,j] or (np.random.rand() < tau))
        if (j==m):
            is_infected = False
            for neighbor in [Pop[i-1,j],Pop[i,j-1]]:
                if neighbor:
                    B[i,j] = int(Pop[i,j] or (np.random.rand() < tau))
        if (j>0) and (j<m):
            is_infected = False
            for neighbor in [Pop[i-1,j],Pop[i,j+1],Pop[i,j-1]]:
                if neighbor:
                    B[i,j] = int(Pop[i,j] or (np.random.rand() < tau))
    if (j==m):
        if (i==0):
            is_infected = False
            for neighbor in [Pop[i+1,j],Pop[i,j-1],Pop[i-1,j]]:
                if neighbor:
                    B[i,j] = int(Pop[i,j] or (np.random.rand() < tau))

    for i in range(n):       ##changed to: for i in range(1,n-1)        #this is the part that
        for j in range(m):   ##changed to: for j in range(1,m-1)        #works excpet for the 
            is_infected = False                                         #final row and column 
            for neighbor in [Pop[i-1,j],Pop[i,j-1], Pop[i+1,j], Pop[i,j+1]]:
                if neighbor:
                    B[i,j] = int(Pop[i,j] or (np.random.rand() < tau))

    return B


def vaccinate(Pop,i,j,n,m,mu):
    V = copy(Pop)                      #since this function is purely random and doesn't rely on
    for i in range(n):                 #neighbor values, it runs fine
        for j in range(m):
            if Pop[i,j] == -2 or Pop[i,j] == -1 or Pop[i,j] > 0:
                V[i,j] = Pop[i,j]
            if Pop[i,j] == 0:
                t = (np.random.rand() < mu)
                if (t==True):
                    V[i,j] = -2               

    return V


i = 0
j = 0
n = 10
m = 10
k = int(input("How many days should it take to recover?"))
tau = 0.5
mu = 0.2
D = np.zeros((k + 1,n,m))
A = np.zeros((n,m))

n1 = random.sample(range(n),1)
m1 = random.sample(range(m),1)
A[n1,m1] = 1
print(A)


for d in range(k):
    D[d,:,:] = A                           #rather than a for loop would it be easier/better to 
    A = vaccinate(A,i,j,n,m,mu)            #implement a while loop?
    A = infect(A,i,j,n-1,m-1,tau)
    print(A)
D[k,:,:] = A
```

should i maybe make the entire matrix one row and column larger and just pad it with zeros?
I don't actually have to present the final matrix, it is solely for computational purposes so maybe that could work.
But i do have to have the simulation terminate once all values within the matrix are not equal to zero. Is there a way around this? Could I just delete the extra row and column before then or since im placing the function into a thread, will it screw everything up?

as for the while loop:

```
def infectAll(Pop,n,m,tau):
    Aout = copy(Pop)
    #for i in range(n):
        #for j in range(m):
    if Pop[i,j] == -2:
        Aout = Pop[i,j]
        vac = []
    if Pop[i,j] == -1:
        Aout = Pop[i,j]
    if Pop[i,j]>0 and Pop[i,j]<=k:
        Aout[i,j] = Pop[i,j] + 1
        inf = []
    if Pop[i,j]>k:
        Aout[i,j] = -1

    if Pop[i,j] == 0:
        Aout = infect(Pop,i,j,n,m,tau)
        if Aout[i,j]==0:
            Aout = vaccinate(Pop,i,j,n,m,nu)

    return Aout


A[n1,m1] = 1
d = 0
print(A)                               #i need d to count the iterations per day, but i also need
while d < 100:                         #to be able to creat 3 different vectors base on the 
     for i in range(n):                #matrix data (# total recovered, total #vaccinated and 
        for j in range(m):             #total infected per day
           if A[i,j]>=0:
              A = infectAll(A,n,m,tau)
              d = d+1 

            else:
              break
```

Comment: If `i==n`, you execute some additional code, but then you go on to execute the code for the normal case anyway. Is that what you wanted? Also, I'm seeing a notable lack of `elif`s here. They are very helpful when you want to take exactly one of several options.

Comment: do you really mean infectAll(A,n,m,tau) and not infectAll(A,i,j,tau)? and do you really mean Aout = A[i,j] and not Aout[i,j] = A[i,j]? Note that range(n) returns numbers 0 to n-1, so I don't see how i can ever be equal to n. What you describe sounds will likely hide the real issue and bite you later; I would remove it, create something that runs (no syntax, no semantic errors like Aout=A[i,j] etc) and state specifically which line you get "improper indexing" (exact message, traceback, etc). Exiting the loop is a separate unrelated question, you should post it separately.